# Javascript If doesn't equal OR doesn't equal

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue making this work:

```
status_ = 'Not Contacted'

if (!(status_ == "Contacted") || (status_ == "Not Contacted") || (status_ == "Not Sure")) {
    console.log('didnt match: '+status_)} else{console.log('matched: '+status_)}
```

It returns - `didnt match: Not Contacted`

but if I change `status_ = 'Contacted'` I get `matched: Contacted`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "wrong" mean? `(status_ == "Not Contacted")` this condition matches.

Comment: The NOT only works for the first condition

Comment: What is the issue you're having, the code is functioning correctly.

Comment: Your if statement is true if: status_ doesn't equal "Contacted" or status_ equals "Not Contacted" or status_ == "Not Sure". Sounds like its working as you wrote it.

Comment: Please, can you give some examples of expected and actual results, please? At the moment I see 2 examples with actual results only.

Comment: Can u give some input and output samples or explain what is been looked for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NOT only works for the first condition, change the parentheses

```
if (!(status_ == "Contacted" || status_ == "Not Contacted" || status_ == "Not Sure")) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the operator precedence and your bracketing, your line says:

> If the status **is not** "Contacted", or **is** "Not Contacted", or **is** "Not Sure"